# Most efficient way to loop through array in array

Tags: php, arrays, foreach

A bit of a newbie question but I'll ask anyway:

Currently when I have an array inside an array and I want to get all the array's values I am using a `foreach` loop inside a `foreach` loop. For example:

```
$array = [
    $inner_array1 = [1, 2, 3, 4],
    $inner_array2 = [a, b, c, d]
];

foreach ($array as $arr) {
    foreach ($arr as $a) {
        echo $a;
    }
}
```

Is there a better, more efficient way to do that?

Comment: It is fine using two loop will work fine and i guess this is only the way to loop through the array inside an array

Comment: If you need all values, this is the only way to do it as far as I know. You could merge the arrays to one flat but not sure that will help in performance

Comment: @someone you should take the tour: https://stackoverflow.com/tour

Answer (score 0):

You can use `recursive function` in case if you will have more than 2 nested arrays

```
$array = [
    'inner_array1' => [1, 2, 3, 4],
    'inner_array2' => ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
];

function loop($array){
    foreach($array as $value){
        if(is_array($value)){
            loop($value);
        }else{
            echo $value;
        }
    }
}
loop($array);
```

[Test here](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/e55aab65add023fb808efe36e72e1410d2a101d3)

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at array_walk_recursive? It's not necessarily more efficient but it might be better, depending on what you are trying to do.

Here is an example, with your arrays (as above). The example ignores the keys (to match your sample) but they are available. Your sample only goes one level but you could make it go more, if you needed to.

```
<?php
$array = [
    $inner_array1 = [1, 2, 3, 4],
    $inner_array2 = [a, b, c, d]
];

function test_print($item, $key)
{
    echo $item;
}

array_walk_recursive($array, 'test_print');
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

I had to test what I wrote in comments and it is faster to first merge the array then loop it.

```
$all = array_merge($array["arr1"], $array["arr2"]);
foreach ($all as $a) {
    echo $a;
}
```

is faster than doing nested loops as in question.
See results https://3v4l.org/aFP6o on all methods.